# How to describe different styles of pixel fonts?

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, style-identification

I came across this problem while trying to search through [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) for an alternative to the [Press Start 2P](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Press+Start+2P?query=CodeMan38) font (reason being that it is not well supported elsewhere).

I know that even though the pixel style is a category itself, many of the pixel fonts also embody characteristics of general font classifications like serif/san serif, cursive, etc. but these are usually not specified in the description of the font itself.

In fact, it seems like pixel fonts are usually related to the type of technology that it was used in (like arcade machines or older computer monitors or command prompts).

Does anyone know of a good list of different types of pixel fonts or classifications (or just a good alternative to Press Start 2P)?

Answer (score 2):

**Press Start 2P Regular** is in the Display category. Display typefaces are not meant for running text or general headlines. Display faces are used in print advertisements, ephemeral items like menus, and web pages. There are many sub-categories of Display type; "pixel" or "pixelated", or "jagged", or "computer" would all describe Press Start 2P.

The Google font PressStart2P-Regular.ttf is an OpenType TrueType typeface which should be compatible with any graphics, office, or imaging software.

Comment: +1 Do you know any fonts off the top of your head that looks similar? It is hard to find pixel type fonts by search since I don't have quite the right keywords for it.

Comment: @MichaelLai I don't, because I don't usually use that style. What is the reason you don't want to use PressStart2P?